# Getting a version number in Eclipse context root via Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-wtp

I've got a web project where I'd like to have the major version number in the final build name. So for example, it should be `myproject-v2`.

Using the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html) I've managed to get this working in my normal Maven build process by adding the following to my pom:

```xml
<build>
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}-v${parsedVersion.majorVersion}</finalName>

  <plugins>
    <!-- Used to build the parsedVersion property for use above -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>parse-version</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>parse-version</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

That works great via Maven & I get a `myproject-v0.war` at the end that I can deploy.

But within Eclipse, it always gets deployed as `myproject-v${parsedVersion.majorVersion}`. So it's not found the new variable - fair enough. But no matter what I try, I can't seem to get Eclipse to pick up the result from the build helper plugin

**Does anyone have any suggestions on what I could try?**  Here's what I have tried already:
* Setting the final build name, the `warName` property on the `maven-war-plugin` and the `m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot` property to my build name pattern.
* Binding the parse-version to a number of different goals (e.g. `clean`, `package`)

But I'm running low on ideas. If I can't do it automatically, I'll just hard code the value but it would be nice to have it done automatically.

Comment: Do you run the ``build-helper:parse-version`` goal from within Eclipse, before you build?

Comment: No but I don't do for Maven either & that works. It binds by default to the validate phase, the first phase in the default build lifecycle.  I also don't want to have to manually do a manual Maven build. I'd like it to be part of whatever Eclipse does to run it's Maven build.